# Limit checkboxes based on selected radio buttons

Tags: javascript, vb.net, radio-button

is it possible to limit the number of checkbox according to the radio button that user have previously selected? I have 4 radio buttons & 4 checkboxes.

 When user select the first radio button, user is allowed to select 1 checkbox.

 When user select the second radio button, user is allowed to select 2 checkbox.
When user select the third radio button, user is allowed to select 3 checkbox. and so on. 

I've been to this, but it's not what I want. [Limit checkboxes with jquery based on checked radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865687/limit-checkboxes-with-jquery-based-on-checked-radio-buttons) 


This is what I've tried. but it doesnt work for the second radio button.

```
function chkcontrol(j) {
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.cb.length; i++) {

        if (RadioButton1.Checked) Then
        {
            if (total > 1) {
                alert("Please Select only 1")
                document.form1.cb[j].checked = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (RadioButton2.Checked) Then
        {
            if (total > 2) {
                alert("Please Select only 2")
                document.form1.cb[j].checked = false;
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (document.form1.cb[i].checked) {
            total = total + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What language or framework are you using? Please add tags. If it is JavaScript then this is case-sensitive: **checked**.

You are also returning `false`, but not returning `true`, which is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop should be separate from the other code. Loop through the checkboxes, totalling how many are checked. Then, separately after this, check the radio-buttons.

```
var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.cb.length; i++) {
    if (document.form1.cb[i].checked) {
        total += 1;
    }
}
// now look at the radio buttons
```

Comment: But shouldnt we loop through radio buttons first determining which has been selected and then count the number of checkbox that has been checked?

Answer (score 0):

Your case .. In VB

```
Function ChkSum() as Integer
   Dim nChkSum as Integer 
   if checkbox1.Checked then nchksum += 1
   if checkbox2.Checked then nchksum += 1
   if checkbox3.Checked then nchksum += 1
   if checkbox4.Checked then nchksum += 1
   Return nChkSum 
End Function

Function LimitCheck() as Integer
   if radiobutton1.checked then return 1
   if radiobutton2.checked then return 2
   if radiobutton3.checked then return 3
   if radiobutton4.checked then return 4
End Function
```

So you can control check limit in checkbox checkedchanged event

```
Private Sub MyCheckBox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged

  Dim chk as CheckBox = CType(Sender,CheckBox)
  If chk.Checked then
     if chksum > limitcheck Then chk.Checked = False
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: oh, how do I make the checkedchanged event? lol, im a newbie in terms of VS 2008. :x

Comment: for this code .. you have to use form with radiobutton 1,2,3,4 and checkbox 1,2,3,4 .. then copy this code into yours

Comment: i've used form with radiobutton as stated. but there's still error for the CheckBox1 and so on in my behind code

Comment: @user2353680 : Maybe there's a mistake .. try again